# How to open PDF files with Adobe reader directly?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-535, pdf, microsoft-edge

Whenever I try to open a PDF file it opens with **Edge** browser and not with **Reader** . For doing so I have to open Reader and have to locate them manually. Is there any way to open them directly? I have recently upgraded from WP8.1 to W10M and my phone is 535 DS running W10M (14393.693).This problem I face only for (.pdf) format not with others as when I try to open a C language program it gives me a screen to choose the app. See the screenshot

[image]

Comment: Worth noting that the Reader app is deprecated, and itself recommends using Edge...

Comment: @RowlandShaw what is deprecated?

Comment: The Reader app itself is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not open the pdf through adobe reader, however it opens though Microsoft edge in Windows phone.
So I did

1. Create a folder inside document folder in sd card or phone.
2. Move pdfs to this folder.
3. Open adobe reader - SD card/phone - document.

Enjoy reading through adobe reader

Comment: I moved the files to the SD card root. There are three PDFs there, Acrobat reader sees one, but not the other two.

Answer (score 3):

Currently there is now way to choose default apps for file types in windows 10. But in build 14393 it was fixed and now when you are to open a pdf file from File Explorer with [Adobe Acrobat Reader](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfj2gh) installed in your phone, you will see this screen[image] where you can select the Adobe reader to open the pdf file.

Comment: Which build are you running? I am running the latest production built and I don't see this screen. Are you running any insider builds?

Comment: Thats what I was talking about @Kolappan

Comment: And @Suneel what build are you using?

Comment: I am on the Anniversary Update available for general public release. I am not in insider ring. Build: 14393.189

Comment: Yup...... updating on build 14393.448 resolved my problem. Thanks